# Remove system colors from TcxDBColorCombobox

Tags: delphi, colors, devexpress, systemcolors

I have a **TcxDBColorCombobox** and I want the drop down to not include the system colors like **clBtnFace**, so it only includes colors like **clRed**.  Additionally I would like it to include **clWindow** and **clWindowText**, but I can add those as custom colors if necessary.  The process should be the same as for **TcxColorCombobox**.  I am sure I will figure it out eventually, but I thought I would see if someone else has experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Properties.PrepareList := cxplHTML4;
```

Comment: I was just trying that property as you answer this.  Thanks!